# Split the given integer value as date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

20160116
Suppose this is the data with datatype integer in a column and now I want to convert it like 2016/01/16 or 2016-01-16 and datatype as date. My column name is system and dataframe is df. How can I do that?

I tried using many date format function but It was not good enough to achieve the answer.

Answer (score 2):

convert using to_datetime, provide the format
then convert to the format of your desire

```
pd.to_datetime(df['dte'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
```

```
0    2016/01/06
Name: dte, dtype: object
```

Comment: It was giving an error

Comment: what error are you getting? the solution was based on the description in your question. A 8 digit integer date, that you wanted to convert to a date format and datetime type.  @rakeshkumarvishwakarma

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.replace` we can try:

```py
df["date"] = df["system"].astype(str).str.replace(r'(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})', r'\1/\2/\3', regex=True)
```